Passing modprobe options through environment
man modprobe says in the ENVIRONMENT section:

The MODPROBE_OPTIONS environment variable can also be used to pass
arguments to modprobe.

But this is unclear. Suppose for example that I want to force the module search path by faking the kernel version string. That is the -S option. Should it be:

MODPROBE_OPTIONS='-S fake-version' or
MODPROBE_OPTIONS='-Sfake-version' or
MODPROBE_OPTIONS='--set-version fake-version' or
MODPROBE_OPTIONS='--set-version=fake-version' or maybe
MODPROBE_OPTIONS='set-version=fake-version'

?? This is a situation where a single example would have made all the difference.
Thanks,
Ian

Probably it would just consider the string as space-separated values and the values would be passed as arguments (as if they are directly typed after modprobe).

The contents of MODPROBE_OPTIONS are prepended to any existing arguments, with no processing other than splitting on spaces.
So if you want to end up with
modprobe -S fake-version module-foo

you’d set
MODPROBE_OPTIONS="-S fake-version"

and then (with the variable exported) run
modprobe module-foo

